# C++ Compressing size of integer down to 2 bits?

Tags: c++, integer, compression, encode, bit

I am doing a little game physics networking project right now, and I am trying to optimize the packets I am sending using this guide:

https://gafferongames.com/post/snapshot_compression/

In the "Optimize Quaternions" section it says:

> Don’t always drop the same component due to numerical precision issues. Instead, find the component with the largest absolute value and ENCODE its index using two bits [0,3] (0=x, 1=y, 2=z, 3=w), then send the index of the largest component and the smallest three components over the network

Now my question is, how do I encode an integer down to 2 bits... or have I misunderstood the task?

I know very little about compressing data, but reducing a 4 byte integer (32 bits) down to ONLY 2 bits seems a bit insane to me. Is that even possible, or have I completely misunderstood everything?

EDIT:
Here is some code of what I have so far:

```
void HavNetConnection::sendBodyPacket(HavNetBodyPacket bp)
{
  RakNet::BitStream bsOut;
  bsOut.Write((RakNet::MessageID)ID_BODY_PACKET);

  float maxAbs = std::abs(bp.rotation(0));
  int maxIndex = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
  {
    float rotAbs = std::abs(bp.rotation(i));
    if (rotAbs > maxAbs) {
      maxAbs = rotAbs;
      maxIndex = i;
    }
  }

  bsOut.Write(bp.position(0));
  bsOut.Write(bp.position(1));
  bsOut.Write(bp.position(2));
  bsOut.Write(bp.linearVelocity(0));
  bsOut.Write(bp.linearVelocity(1));
  bsOut.Write(bp.linearVelocity(2));
  bsOut.Write(bp.rotation(0));
  bsOut.Write(bp.rotation(1));
  bsOut.Write(bp.rotation(2));
  bsOut.Write(bp.rotation(3));
  bsOut.Write(bp.bodyId.toRawInt(bp.bodyId));
  bsOut.Write(bp.stepCount);

  // Send body packets over UDP (UNRELIABLE), priority could be low.
  m_peer->Send(&bsOut, MEDIUM_PRIORITY, UNRELIABLE, 
      0, RakNet::UNASSIGNED_SYSTEM_ADDRESS, true);
}
```

Comment: It sounds like the 4 bits are used to denote _which_ component is being referred to, not its value

Comment: @alterigel Still, how do I send a value that is only 2 bits. There isn't a data type that is 2 bits large is there? I am a newbie in C++ but most other languages I have used don't have data types that are under 1 byte. Maybe I am talking out of my ass here but I don't know that much about compression.

Comment: The previous text is relevant. It says you can drop one of the components and reconstruct it. Now the part you mention says that instead of always dropping the same one, you should pick the best one, and use the 2 bits to tell the decoder which one it was.

Comment: @DanMašek But how do I "use" the 2 bits? Like there isn't a datatype that stores 2 bits is there? I need to send something over the network that I will decode on the other side but the thing I send need to be 2 bits in size...right?

Comment: I feel like I am being stupid and completely missing the point here...

Comment: @RemyLebeau So a byte is 8-bits in the form of 0's and 1's. For example 00000011. So I should try to represent the number 0,1,2,3 (since those are the possible indexes) using only the last 2 bits in the byte right? But how do I do this in practice? Do I use a char or something... and how (wouldn't a char still take up 1 byte in memory no matter what I do)?

Comment: @Schytheron the smallest data type you can send is an 8-bit byte. The 2 bits can't be sent by themselves, but they can be combined with bits for other values to complete the byte. Data must be an even multiple of 8 bits, and in the author's example, he's actually sending 4 values in 29 bits (2 + 9 + 9 + 9), which requires sending 32 bits.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Damn... this makes everything a whole lot more complicated since I am sending my data as multiple bytes at a time. Ill upload some code in a minute.

Comment: Let's simplify this. Let's say we know that A+B+C+D=100 every time. That means I can send you (A,B,C) or (A,B,D) or (A,C,D) or (B,C,D) along with information which one I omitted, and you can calculate the missing one in any scenario. The 2 bits to represent the missing component are already saving bits as opposed to sending the component itself. | Now there are variable length codes, which can, for example, uniquely encode and decode smaller numbers using fewer bits (trade off being that large numbers need more). You could then pick the smallest 3 values to use the least bits.

Comment: The idea is that you would treat the whole packet as a stream of bits (and then add some padding at the end.

Comment: @Schytheron you are taking on a complex subject when you don't even understand basic fundamentals first. You need to understand data types, bit representations, and bit shifting/twiddling before you can tackle this effectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution to your problem is to use [bitfields](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field):

```
// working type (use your existing Quaternion implementation instead)
struct Quaternion{
    float w,x,y,z;
    Quaternion(float w_=1.0f, float x_=0.0f, float y_=0.0f, float z_=0.0f) : w(w_), x(x_), y(y_), z(z_) {}
};

struct PacketQuaternion
{
    enum LargestElement{
        W=0, X=1, Y=2, Z=3,
    };
    LargestElement le : 2; // 2 bits;
    signed int i1 : 9, i2 : 9, i3 : 9;  // 9 bits each

    PacketQuaternion() : le(W), i1(0), i2(0), i3(0) {}

    operator Quaternion() const { // convert packet quaternion to  regular quaternion
        const float s = 1.0f/float(1<<8); // scale int to [-1, 1]; you could also scale to [-sqrt(.5), sqrt(.5)]
        const float f1=s*i1, f2 = s*i2, f3 = s*i3;
        const float f0 = std::sqrt(1.0f - f1*f1-f2*f2-f3*f3);
        switch(le){
        case W: return Quaternion(f0, f1, f2, f3);
        case X: return Quaternion(f1, f0, f2, f3);
        case Y: return Quaternion(f1, f2, f0, f3);
        case Z: return Quaternion(f1, f2, f3, f0);
        }
        return Quaternion(); // default, can't happen
    }
};
```

If you have a look at the assembler code this generates, you will see a bit of shifting to extract `le` and `i1` to `i3` -- essentially the same code you could write manually as well.

Your `PacketQuaternion` structure will always occupy a whole number of bytes, so (on any non-exotic platform) you will still waste 3 bits (you could just use 10 bits per integer field here, unless you have other use for those bits).

I left out the code to convert from regular quaternion to `PacketQuaternion`, but that should be relatively simple as well.

Generally (as always when networking is involved), be extra careful that data is converted correctly in all directions, especially, if different architectures or different compilers are involved!

Also, as others have noted, make sure that network bandwidth indeed is a bottle neck before doing aggressive optimization here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing they want you to fit the 2 bits into some value you are already sending that doesn't need all of the available bits, or to pack several small bit fields into a single int for transmission.

You can do things like this:

```
// these are going to be used as 2 bit fields,
// so we can only go to 3.
enum addresses
{
    x = 0,    // 00
    y = 1,    // 01
    z = 2,    // 10
    w = 3     // 11
};

int val_to_send;

// set the value to send, and shift it 2 bits left.
val_to_send = 1234;
// bit pattern:  0000 0100 1101 0010

// bit shift left by 2 bits
val_to_send = val_to_send << 2;
// bit pattern:  0001 0011 0100 1000

// set the address to the last 2 bits.
// this value is address w (bit pattern 11) for example...
val_to_send |= w;
// bit pattern: 0001 0011 0100 1011

send_value(val_to_send);
```

On the receive end:

```
receive_value(&rx_value);

// pick off the address by masking with the low 2 bits
address = rx_value & 0x3;
// address now = 3 (w)

// bit shift right to restore the value
rx_value = rx_value >> 2;
// rx_value = 1234 again.
```

You can 'pack' bits this way, any number of bits at a time.

```
int address_list;
// set address to w (11)
address_list = w;
// 0000 0011

// bit shift left by 2 bits
address_list = address_list << 2;
// 0000 1100

// now add address x (00)
address_list |= x;
// 0000 1100

// bit shift left 2 more bits
address_list = address_list << 2;
// 0011 0000

// add the address y (01)
address_list |= y;
// 0011 0001

// bit shift left 2 more bits
address_list = address_list << 2;
// 1100 0100

// add the address z. (10)
address_list |= z;
// 1100 0110
// w x  y z are now in the lower byte of 'address_list'
```

This packs 4 addresses into the lower byte of 'address_list';

You just have to do the unpacking on the other end.

This has some implementation details to work out.  You only have 30 bits now for the value, not 32.  If the data is a signed int, you have more work to do to avoid shifting the sign bit out to the left, etc.

But, fundamentally, this is how you can stuff bit patterns into data that you are sending.

Obviously this assumes that sending is more expensive than the work of packing bits into bytes and ints, etc.  This is often the case, especially where low baud rates are involved, as in serial ports.

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of possible understandings and misunderstandings in play here.
[ttemple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49214338/c-compressing-size-of-integer-down-to-2-bits/49215032#49215032) addressed your technical problem of sending less than a byte.
I want to reiterate the more theoretical points.

## This is not done

You originally misunderstood the quoted passage.
We do not use two bits to say “not sending 2121387”,
but to say “not sending z-component”.
That these match exactly, should be easy to see.

## This is impossible

If you want to send a 32 bit integer which might take any of the 2^32 possible values,
you need *at least* 32 bits.
As n bits can represent at most exactly 2^n states,
any smaller amount of bits just will not suffice.

## This is kinda possible

Beyond your actual question:
When we relax the requirement that we will always use 2 bits
and have sufficiently strong assumptions
on the probability distribution of the values,
we can get the **expected value** of the number of bits down.
Ideas like this are used all over the place in the linked article.

### Example

Let c be some integer that is 0 almost all the time (97%, say)
and can take any value the rest of the time (3%).
Then we can take one bit to say whether “c is zero”
and need no further bits most of the time.
In the cases where c is not zero,
we spend another 32 bits to encode it regularly.
In total we need 0.97*1+0.03*(1+32) = 1.96 bits *on average*.
But we need 33 bits *sometimes*,
which makes this compatible with my earlier assertion of impossibility.

## This is complicated

Depending on your background (in math, bit-fiddling etc.) it might just seem like an enormous, unknowable piece of black magic.
(It isn't. You can learn this stuff.)
You do not seem completely lost and a quick learner
but I agree with [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49214338/c-compressing-size-of-integer-down-to-2-bits#comment85434161_49214338)
that you seem to be out of your depth.

**Do you really need to do this?**
Or are you optimizing prematurely?
If it runs well enough, let it run.
Concentrate on the important stuff.

Comment: The article he references discusses the need.  He is trying to dramatically reduce the bandwidth requirements of a network based game.  His example reduces 17 megabits per second to about 600 killobits per second by a series of optimizations, including reducing 32 bit ints to 9 bit resolution, etc.

Comment: @ttemple No, the article discusses the need for *the project discussed in the article*, it neither does nor can discuss the need for *the project of the OP*.

Comment: @ttemple The OP themselves now answered that they do not need to optimize in the current state of their project.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was unclear.  I was not implying that the article discussed the OP's project.  The app in the article was the subject of the  article.  By 'His example', I meant the example of the writer of the article, not the example of the OP.  Sorry for the confusion.